# Minimal language dependency for webservice client

Tags: webservice-client

What is the simplest (setup wise) solution for a webservice client?
I need to make a lightweight app that will connect to and perform actions against a specific webservice server.

The main requirement is there request and response will be SOAP, there will be no libraries that need to be installed for this to run.
It may be implemented in any language and should run on Windows only.

Comment: A web service that returns an ascii string.

Comment: My question is about implementation of the client, the server is out of my hands...

Comment: This posting gives no information that can guide a decision. At the least, you have to indicate the type of information sent and received (raw XML? SOAP? JSON?). And the requirement of "no libraries that need to be installed" also needs refinement: if you package the libraries with the client, does that constitute installing them? If you need a runtime (as for .NET or Java), does that constitute a library? And what do you want to do with this client? Your browser may be the simplest setup.

Comment: You're right - updated that. Should use SOAP.

Comment: Since you're on Windows, use whatever .Net language you prefer, and learn the .Net webservice stack. You're still not giving anyone enough information to give you a valid answer, which to me indicates that you haven't completely thought through your needs.

Comment: I currently have a small .NET app that does the job, but this requires .NET framework.
I have also had a look at C++ libraries but as far as I saw they also need libraries to be installed.
One option could maybe be to create an executable of a scripting language app as this would contain all I need. Can webservices be accessed using regular http libraries is I format the request message correctly?

Answer (score 0):

A webservice can get called using javascript, from an HTML page. Put it online, and provide the people with the URL, should be simple enough. Assuming people know you can enter a URL in a browser.

Comment: What about certificates etc.?